# C++ string - strange behaviour when using initialization list constructor

Tags: c++, string, c++11, constructor, initializer-list

I know that I can use array of chars and also initialization list to fill a string.

It looks that the compiler makes some implicit promotion from int to initializer_list or allocator. But I don't know why it doesn't give me any warning and why it makes it implicit.

Could you explain to me what happens with strings s4, and s5?

http://ideone.com/5Agc2T

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class A{
};

int main() {

    // string::string(charT const* s)
    string s1("12345");
    // 5 - because constructor takes into account null-terminated character
    cout << s1.size() << endl;      

    // string(std::initializer_list<charT> ilist)
    string s2({'1','2','3','4','5'});   
    // 5 - because string is built from the contents of the initializer list init.  
    cout << s2.size()<<endl;

    // string::string(charT const* s, size_type count)
    string s3("12345",3);
    // 3 -  Constructs the string with the first count characters of character string pointed to by s
    cout << s3.size() << endl;

    // basic_string( std::initializer_list<CharT> init,const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() ); - ?
    string s4({'1','2','3','4','5'},3);
    // 2 - why this compiles (with no warning) and what this result means?
    cout << s4.size() << endl;



    string s5({'1','2','3','4','5'},5);
    // 0 - why this compiles (with no warning) and what this result means?
    cout << s5.size() << endl;

    // basic_string( std::initializer_list<CharT> init,const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
    // doesn't compile, no known conversion for argument 2 from 'A' to 'const std::allocator<char>&'
    //string s6({'1','2','3','4','5'},A());
    //cout << s6.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain to me what you would expect instead what happens? I can't see anything unintentional in this code.

Comment: Yes, of course. I've expected the same behaviour for both constructors, the one taking array of chars and initializer lists as well.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
string s6({'1','2','3','4','5'},3);
string s7({'1','2','3','4','5'},5);
```

Actually, those initializations don't just call the `std::initializer_list` constructor. The second argument cannot be implicitly converted to `std::allocator`, so other constructors are considered. The constructor called is the one with this signature:

```
basic_string( const basic_string& other, 
              size_type pos, 
              size_type count = std::basic_string::npos,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

The `std::initializer_list` constructor is used to create a temporary `std::string` from the braced-init-list to pass as the `other` argument to the above constructor. The temporary can bind to that because it's a reference-to-const. The second argument, therefore, is the `pos` argument, which is used as the starting point of a substring copy construction.

So `s6` is the characters in the interval `[3, 5)` (i.e. `"45"`) and `s7` is the characters in the interval `[5,5)` (i.e. `""`).

Comment: Wow. Those pitfalls are an example of what makes C++ hard to get, sometimes.

Comment: I don't understand what else OP was expecting?!

Comment: They were expecting the compiler to complain that there was no implicit conversion from `5` to `const std::allocator<char>&` because they were only considering that constructor as an option.